# Ranking vector entries by magnitude in MATLAB using vector operations

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, vector, ranking

I'm try to find short, efficient vector operations that efficiently rank entries in a vector by their relative magnitude. For example, if a vector is:

```
A = [212 314 196];
```

I want a function that returns:

```
B = [2 3 1];
```

I'm messing around with the sort function, but all of my solutions so far have what I think might be an unnecessary for loop. I'm stumped--does anyone know a more elegant way?

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/21/reversal-of-a-sort/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loren has a nice blog entry on [inverting the sort order](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/21/reversal-of-a-sort).

Answer (score 0):

[~,B]=sort(A) when A is a row vector.

[~,B]=sort(A,2) when A is a matrix and you'd like the relative magnitudes for each row.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the numbers in the vector A are different, you can find their ranking using the transpose of A:

```
sum(A > A.') + 1
```

For your vector this results in:

> [2 3 1]